# Model Association issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes, rails-geocoder

Hopefully this will be simple. But I've hunted for a couple hours now and can't seem to get this to work. I have users who have multiple addresses, I'm trying to use Geocoder gem to display these users by a zip code search, my code is very similar to what is in the Geocoder Railscast.

Here's my controller attempt 1 and returns "undefined method `Addresses'"

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @profiles = Profile.Addresses.near(params[:search], 25, :order => :distance)
    @title = "Therapists Near " + :search
  else
  @profiles = Profile.all
  @title = "Everyone"
  end
end
```

This is attempt number 2, this returns "uninitialized constant ProfilesController::Addresses" (I don't know if the Profile.where bit will work, but its not even getting to that part...)

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      addresses = Addresses.near(params[:search], 25, :order => :distance)
      @profiles = Profile.where(:id => addresses.id)
      @title = "Therapists Near " + :search
    else
    @profiles = Profile.all
    @title = "Everyone"
    end
  end
```

Here's my models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:street].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  geocoded_by :street
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :street_changed?
```

Thanks a lot for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional, you may change to the following to get all profiles:

```
addresses = Address.near(params[:search], 25, :order => :distance)

@profiles = addresses.map{ |ad| ad.profile }.uniq unless addresses.nil?
```

If there are matched addresses, then find the profile from each address.

Comment: This worked almost perfect. Had to switch the .blank? to .nil?

Comment: You get back an array which can't be paginated

Answer (score 0):

For number 2, you have to change from `Addresses.near(params[:search], 25, :order => :distance)` to `Address.near(params[:search], 25, :order => :distance)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found i couldn't paginate with the accepted answer.  So I got pretty grubby:

```
addresses = Address.near(params[:search], 25, :order => :distance)
locations_id_array = []  
addresses.each do |address| 
  addresses_id_array << address.id
end  
@profiles  = Profile.where(:address_id => addresses_id_array).paginate(:page => params[:page],  :per_page => 5).order('name DESC')
```

If anyone has a nicer, scaleable way to do this (preferably with scopes) I'd love to hear it.